# Return data from child process to parent in perl

Tags: perl, background, return, fork, parent

I am using Forks::Super to run 8 background processes which should return results to the parent when completed. I have tried several methods without success. I am current trying out the bg_eval method. The child process returns a Data::Table reference. However, when i try to execute one of the Data::Table methods (nofRow) I get the following error:

> Can't locate object method "nofRow" via package "Forks::Super::LazyEval::BackgroundScalar" at top_interest_per_sub_faster.pl line 135,  line 268.

The relevant part of my perl code below. I run a method "merge_summarize_tables" using bg_eval and push the results to an array @summary_files_subset_results.

```
  use Forks::Super 'bg_eval';

  my $result = bg_eval{merge_summarize_tables(@spliced_files)};
  push(@summary_files_subset_results, $result);
```

Later when I try to execute one of the table methods I get the error I shared above:

```
my $hits_per_interest_per_subscriber = $summary_files_subset_results[0];
print("Rows merged " . commify($hits_per_interest_per_subscriber->nofRow) ."\n");
```

A simplified version of the method called:

```
sub merge_summarize_tables
{  
  # removing a lot of irrelevant code here. In the end the function returns a table ...
  my $table_to_merge = Data::Table::fromCSV($file, 0, undef);
  return $table_to_merge;
}
```

Comment: You've not shown the call to "nofRow", which makes it difficult to guess what the issue might be.

Comment: Sorry, I have modified it now.

Comment: Well, it's clearly not converting the proxy `BackgroundScalar` object into its value as advertised. I'm wondering whether use as a method-object counts as "used in an expression".

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you'll want to call `_fetch` manually in this case. It seems to overload various things like dereferencing, addition, string-concat etc but doesn't work for object method calls.

This works though:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use v5.14;
use warnings;

use Forks::Super qw(bg_eval);
use Data::Printer colored => 0;

package C {
        use Moo;

        has 'x' => (is => 'rw', required => 1);
};

sub c_one {
        my $c = C->new(x=>1);
        return $c;
}

# main
my $res = bg_eval { c_one(); };
say ref($res);
say "-----";

my $res2 = $res->_fetch();
p $res2;
say "x = ".$res2->x;
exit;
```

Comment: I think it's working now. But I am facing a couple of other issues so I'm not quite sure yet:

1. There is no output from the children from bg_eval, but when using fork I can see the output of print
2. One child returns. I can see the others in memory but they do not seem to be doing anything. The parent keeps waiting forever for them to return. If I fix the first issue I might be able to know what's going on.

Comment: Actually, no, it's not working. My code is now:

`print "".(localtime).(" Started merging table\n");
my $hits_per_interest_per_subscriber = $summary_files_subset_results[0]->_fetch();
print("Rows merged " . commify($hits_per_interest_per_subscriber->nofRow) ."\n");`

Output just stops here:

**Wed May  7 17:04:07 2014 Started merging table**

Answer (score 1):

I have achieved the result I want by migrating the whole solution to threads rather than forks. It was much easier to retrieve data from children run as threads than forked processes. The threads ran on separate CPUs and utilized all the cores. I Also got output on the screen unlike bg_eval. This is a much better and easier solution in this case.

Here is my updated code:

```
use threads;

# some code to create @spliced_file array of file names

push(@threads, threads->create(\&merge_summarize_tables, @spliced_files)); 

# the method merge_summarize_tables returns a data::table object

foreach (@threads) {
        push(@summary_files_subset_results, $_->join);
        print "Child finished\n";
}

my $hits_per_interest_per_subscriber = $summary_files_subset_results[0];
print("Rows merged " . commify($hits_per_interest_per_subscriber->nofRow) ."\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

`Forks::Super` author here. The return value of `bg_eval` has to be a `Forks::Super::LazyEval::BackgroundScalar` object, so it is a problem to try to directly return some other kind of object. I'll think about how that can be fixed.

One workaround is to wrap your object in an array reference or hash reference, and extract it from a reference in the parent process. For example:

```
# with array reference
$result = bg_eval { [ merge_summarize_tables(@spliced_files) ] };
...
my $hits = $summary_files_subset_results[0];
print("Rows merged " . commify($hits->[0]->nofRow) ."\n");


# with hash reference
$result = bg_eval { { payload => merge_summarize_tables(@spliced_files) } };
...
my $hits = $summary_files_subset_results[0];
print("Rows merged " . commify($hits->{payload}->nofRow) ."\n");


# a scalar reference works too
$result = bg_eval { \merge_summarize_tables(@spliced_files) };
...
my $hits = $summary_files_subset_results[0];
print("Rows merged " . commify($$hits->nofRow) ."\n");
```